# what better place / way to save images with MongoDB / PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, image, nosql

Good morning people,

I have a question,
I am creating a web application in php that will make use of the MongoDB database ie a nosql database.

This application will work with pretty pictures, like an ecommerce. I tried an idea to save the images in the database, but it did not work, so I concluded that it is better to save the image path in database and image typically on a server.

The question is, how best to do this, what is the best server for images, preferably free or very cheap.
How do you guys usually do this, what server do you use?

NOTE: It will be for a commercial application.

Thanks

Comment: Save either on Amazon AWS or FilePicker(https://www.filepicker.io/).

Comment: my head starts to hurt when I hear commercial application and "preferably free or very cheap" for servers.

Comment: There is no such thing as cheap file (or free lol) storage, though S3 is the cheapest I have found so far

Comment: Why do you consider it so important that this is a **commercial** application? Just being commercial says nothing about its scope, size and requirements.

Comment: Best service for images? Try Amazon ec2 , they have this free trial plan. I would store the path in db rather than the image itself.http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are establishing an online business, you should be ready to pay for products and services that will be beneficial for your project. Of course, I'm not telling you to go for the most expensive solution available, I'm telling you not to make your choices by considering their cost first and foremost.

Saving the image itself in the database is rarely a good idea for lots of reasons. If you are okay with people easily guessing your images' paths, you can use something similar to this:

```
http://img.buyfromus.com/products/12736.png
```

where **12736** is the unique ID of the product. That way, you don't have to store the path to the image of each product and can simply build the path in your code or template.

If you do not want people to easily guess your images' paths, you can generate a **unique code** for each product and use that as the filename:

```
http://img.buyfromus.com/products/fc9e5c3935.png
```

where **fc9e5c3935** is the unique code of the product.

These two methods are better than storing the full path to the image of each product.

Depending on the size and type (global, local etc.) of your target audience, the answer to "where should I host my images" changes. If it's going to be a small website, you will probably be fine with using your web server to serve your images as well. If it's not going to be a small one, you can use one or more separate servers to serve your images. If it's going to be a global website with a high traffic, you might want to use one of the cloud solutions such as AWS S3.

If you want more specific suggestions, please edit your post to give more details.